# Find an element in vector<vector<string>>

Tags: c++

I store this file in `vector<vector<string>>`:

```
   1 a aa  # vector of string stored to `vector<vector<string>>`
   2 b bb
   3 c cc  # c -> index == 2
   4 d dd
```

C++ code:

```
vector<vector<string>> myvect = 
    {{"1","a","aa"},
    {"2","b","bb"},
    {"3","c","cc"},
    {"4","d","dd"}};
```

How can I search for  `c` in the second column and get its index (I know it is in the second vector) - the output should be 2.

I want to use `find` or `find_if` function.

Comment: You can't use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), you have to use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a custom predicate. If your compiler supports it, I suggest you also read about [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: @user1436187 The c has two indices.:)

Comment: do you already know/expect the c to be in the second column? what exactly is your problem?

Comment: The index of the vector `c` is in is 2, `c`'s index in that vector is 1. Which one do you want?

Comment: Yes, I know it is in the second column.

Answer (score 1):

If you specificially want to search the 2nd column of the inner vector you can use a `transform_iterator` and regular `find`.

`transform_iterator` is in `boost` would look something like:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::string > > v;
auto lambda = [] ( std::vector< std::string > const& v ) { return v[1]; };

auto transform_end = boost::make_transform_iterator ( v.end() ); 
return std::find( boost::make_transform_iterator( v.begin(), lambda ), 
          transform_end, "c" ) != transform_end;
```

If your inner lambda is to find `"c"` in any position I wouldn't use transform iterator here as we want to return a true/false on each inner vector, not just some transformed value, and we would use find_if on the outer-vector and find on the inner one

```
std::string val = "c";
auto lambda = [ const & ]( std::vector< std::string > const& vInner )
       { return std::find( vInner.begin(), vInner.end(), val ) != v.end(); } ;

return std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), lambda );
```

Comment: Is it the `boost` library? Do you know a good example for `transform_iterator`.

Comment: The above is one example: generally where you want to apply an algorithm to a transformed value of what your collection actually holds. With lambdas and in-place loops they are less used than they were.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to the code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v = 
    {
        { "1", "a", "aa" },
        { "2", "b", "bb" },
        { "3", "c", "cc" },
        { "4", "d", "dd" }
    };

    std::vector<std::string>::iterator second;
    std::string s = "c";

    auto first = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(),
        [&]( std::vector<std::string> &v1 )
        {
            return (( second = std::find( v1.begin(), v1.end(), s ) ) != v1.end() ); 
        } );

    if ( first != v.end() )
    {
        size_t i = std::distance( v.begin(), first );
        size_t j = std::distance( v[i].begin(), second );

        std::cout << v[i][j] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
c
```

Comment: Is not it faster if I put the second column to a temporary vector and search in it!?

Comment: @user1436187 No it will not be faster because you have to create this temporary vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
int column = 1; // Set this to the column you need to search;
string target( "c" ); // Set this to the value you need to find
auto found = find_if( myvect.begin(), myvect.end(), [=]( vector< string > row ){ return row[column] == target; } );

cout << ( found == myvect.end() ? "not found" : ( *found2 )[column] ) << endl;
```

C++11 wont let you define `column` or `target` in the capture, if you want to avoid intermediate variables in C++11 though, you can do this, it's just ugly cause of the `static_cast`. You'd just have to set the `"c"` and `1` to the `target` and `column`:

```
auto found = find_if( myvect.begin(), myvect.end(), bind( equal_to< string >(), "c", bind( static_cast< const string&( vector<string>::* )( size_t ) const >( &vector< string >::operator[] ), placeholders::_1, 1 ) ) );
```

I personally would suggest that if your row size is always the same that you put it in a single `std::vector` like this: `vector<string> myvect = { "1", "a", "aa", "2", "b", "bb", "3", "c", "cc", "4", "d", "dd" };` if you do that you can write a template to search for you which will have significantly more flexibility:

```
template< typename T, int stride >
T* templateFind( const vector< T >& myvect, const T& target, int column )
{
    typedef array< T, stride > rowSize;

    rowSize* end = ( rowSize* )( &*( myvect.begin() ) ) + ( myvect.size() / stride );
    rowSize* result = find_if( ( rowSize* )( &*( myvect.begin() ) ), end, [&]( rowSize row ){ return row[column] == target; } );

    return result == end ? nullptr : ( ( T* )result ) + column;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
string* found = templateFind< string, 3 >( myvect, "c", 1 );

cout << ( found == nullptr ? "not found" : *found ) << endl;
```